# Lazy random generator as observable

Tags: rx-java, reactivex

I need to write random generator as observable. Observer will do something with the next value a long time. So I'd like to emit new random number only when observer wants it or, possible, two extra numbers, but no more.

How to do it?

P.S. If it matters I use Java.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `fromCallable` with `repeat` to get a new value whenever there is a demand from the consumer.

For example:

```
Random random = new Random();
Observable.fromCallable(() -> random.nextDouble())
.repeat()
.map(rnd -> {
    // do something with the random number
    return rnd * 2;
}
.take(50)
.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the little-known `SyncOnSubscribe`:

```
Observable
.create(SyncOnSubscribe.createStateless(observer -> observer.onNext(random.nextDouble))
.map(...)
.take(...)
.subscribe(...)
```

This will work correctly with backpressure.

Comment: For RxJava 2, this has been replaced with `Flowable.generate` or `Flowable.from`... .